# Where in the Ṛgveda (Rig Veda) is Vṛṣaṇaśva? Does anyone have the Sanskrit with translation of Rig Veda 1:51?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, translation-request, ancestry

I recently found out from here that the father of Menā, Vṛṣaṇaśva is not just mentioned in the Brahmanas, but in the Rig-Veda itself. What is a good translation of this verse on the mysterious ancestor of the Parvata?

See here: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/vrishanashva

While the verse of Vṛṣaṇaśva has been found. I wonder what the rest of the hymn says. What especially confuses me is why it says "to him," at the end, when Menā is supposed to be female.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01051.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

king Vṛṣaṇaśva is mentioned in Rig-Veda mandala 1- Sukta 51-Mantra 13.Indra once took birth as a daughter of Vṛṣaṇaśva and her name was Mena.
As you requested , below are the  three translations of the mantra where the king Vṛṣaṇaśva is mentioned in Rig-Veda.

---

[**Translation By H.H.Wilson**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.41620/page/n193/mode/2up)

> अददा अर्भां महते वचस्यवे कक्षीवते वृचयामिन्द्र सुन्वते |
>  मेनाभवो
> **वृषणश्वस्य** सुक्रतो विश्वेत्ता ते सवनेषु प्रवाच्या ||13 ||
>
> adadā arbhāṃ mahate vacasyave kakṣīvate vṛcayāmindra sunvate |
> menābhavo vṛṣaṇaśvasya sukrato viśvet tā te savaneṣu pravācyā ||
>
> Thou hast given Indra , the youthful Vrichayato the aged kakshivat
> praising thee,and offering libations. Thou Sukrutu ,wast **Mena , the
> daughter of Vrishanashwa**. All these thy deeds are to be recited by
> thy worship.

---

Here is translation of [**Ralph Griffith**](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01051.htm)

> 13 To old Kakṣīvān, Soma-presser, skilled in song, O Indra, thou didst
> give the youthful Vṛcayā. Thou, very wise, wast **Menā, Vrsanśva's
> child:** those deeds of thine must all be told at Soma feasts.

---

And here is Hindi translation by [**Shree Ram Sharma Acharya**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v1.98) of AWGP

[image]

Comment: Pushkar, what part of the original Sansrit verse maps to "hai uttam karm Indradev" in the Hindi translation?

Comment: @iruvar - I think it's the word "Sukrato".

Comment: Pushkar, Upvoted for sourcing effort.  Downvoted for not running diligence on translations prior to answering.

Comment: @iruvar - The question asks about where in Rig-Veda? and i have provided the answer. Also the OP is looking for good translations not the commentary. Hence the answer.